# Number of solutions of system of linear equations over finite field

Tags: systems-of-equations, finite-fields, trace, trace-map, field-trace

Suppose $F=GF(2^8)$. Let $u_1,u_2\in K=GF(2^4)$ be linearly independent elements. The functions $x\mapsto tr_n (u_ix)$ are linear functions from $F\to GF(2)$, $i=1,2$. Here $tr_n$ denotes the absolute trace.

Since the functions are linear, I know that there are exactly $2^7$ elements $x$ such that $tr_n(u_ix)=0$, for $i=1,2$.

Computationally, I observed that there are exactly $2^6$ elements such that $ tr_n (u_1x)=0$ and $ tr_n (u_2x)=0$. Since $u_i\in K$, I know that for $x\in K$, both of the traces will be equal to $0$. But how do I determine the remaining $2^6-2^4$ elements. How do I prove that the number of solutions is exactly $2^6$. I have a feeling that it has to do with the linear independence of $u_1$ and $u_2$, but I do not know how to use it.

Comment: Those $2^6-2^4$ elements form three cosets of the intermediate field $K$.

Comment: By transitivity of trace we have
$$tr_8(u_ix)=tr_4(u_i(x+x^{16}))$$ for all $x\in F$. So the solution space of your system consists of the solutions of $x^{16}+x=w$ with $w$ ranging over a 2-dimensional subspace of $K$. If you need to find the solutions on the fly for many different pairs $u_1,u_2$, an approach may be to precompute a list of elements $z_i\in F$ such that $z_i^{16}+z_i=y_i$, $i=1,2,3,4$, where $y_i$s form a basis of $K$. Everything in sight is linear, so having those $z_i$ at hand lets you find the cosets of $K$ forming the solution set.

Comment: I'm a bit curious about the origin of this problem. Is there an application where this is needed?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I want to show that when $x\in GF(2^8)=F$ and $u_1,\ldots, u_4\in K^*$, $K$ subfield of $F$ with $2^4$ elements, are linearly independent, then $(tr_n(u_1x),\ldots,tr_n(u_4x))$  when $x$ goes through $GF(2^8)$ is exactly the multiset consisting of $GF(2)^4$, where each element appears $2^4$ times. That is $$V=\{(tr_n(u_1x),\ldots,tr_n(u_4x)):x\in GF(2^8)\}=\underbrace{GF(2)^4 \cup \ldots GF(2)^4}_{2^4\ sets}.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proving that there are exactly $2^6$ solutions is easy.
Let
$$V_i=\{x\in F\mid tr(u_ix)=0\},$$
$i=1,2$, be the sets of solutions to one of the equations. As you observed they are kernels of a linear transformation $f_i:F\to GF(2), x\mapsto tr(u_ix)$. Because $u_1\neq0\neq u_2$, both are surjective, and, by rank-nullity, have dimension $7$.

Linear independence is equivalent to the assumption that $u_1$ are $u_2$ are distinct and non-zero. The key is the following

**Claim.** The subspaces $V_1$ and $V_2$ are not equal.

**Proof.** Assume contrariwise that $V_1=V_2$. Let $y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_7$ be a basis of $V_1$. We can extend it to a basis of $F$ by joining an eighth element $y_8$. As $y_2\notin V_1=V_2$ we have $tr(u_1y_8)=1=tr(u_2y_8)$. Together with the facts $tr(u_iy_j)=0$, $i=1,2, j=1,2,\ldots,7$. This implies that
$$
tr((u_1+u_2)y_j)=0
$$
for all $j=1,2,\ldots,9$. In other words, $x\mapsto tr((u_1+u_2)x)$ vanishes on all of $F$. By basic properties of the trace maps this implies that $u_1+u_2=0$. In other words $u_1=u_2$. A contradiction.

It follows that $V_1\cap V_2$ is a 6-dimensional subspace. We can re-interpret the intersection as the kernel of the *restriction* of the transformation $f_2$ to $V_1$:
$$
V_1\cap V_2=\operatorname{Ker}(f_2\vert_{V_1})=\{x\in V_1\mid f_2(x)=0\}.
$$
The image of $f_2\vert_{V_1}$ is a subspace of $GF(2)$, so has dimension either $0$ or $1$. Two cases:

- If $f_2\vert_{V_1}$ is the zero map, then it follows that $V_1=V_2$ &endash; a case we excluded.
- If $f_2\vert_{V_1}$ is surjective then, by rank-nullity, its kernel is 6-dimensional. Implying that $V_1\cap V_2$ has exactly $2^6$ elements.

---

For generalizations they key is that the (symmetric) bilinear form $B:F\times F\to GF(2)$
$$
B(x,y)=tr(xy)
$$
is *non-degenerate.* In other words, given a $y\in F$ such that $B(x,y)=0$ for all $x\in F$, we can conclude that we must have $y=0$. For the trace form this is clear.

Whenever we have a non-degenerate bilinear form $B:V\times V\to GF(2)$, $\dim V=n$, it follows that to each subspace $W\subseteq V$, its orthogonal subspace
$$W^\perp=\{z\in V\mid B(x,z)=0 \ \text{for all $x\in W$}\}$$
has the complementary dimension:
$$
\dim W+\dim W^{\perp}=\dim V.
$$
So if next time you have three linearly independent elements $u_1,u_2,u_3$, it is automatic that the system $tr(u_ix)=0$, $i=1,2,3$, has exactly $2^{8-3}=2^5$ solutions.

Undoubtedly you noticed how I used non-degeneracy of the trace form to conclude that $u_1+u_2=0$.

Comment: Non-degeneracy of the bilinear trace form is the key. Here as well as in the generalizations.

Comment: Sorry about adding possibly too much detail. I have been teaching sophomore calculus all semester long- Intensely. Due to pandemic measures :-/

Comment: No, I like detail. Thank you very much! I have a much clearer picture now about the whole concept :)